# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova

Tags: cordova, ios9, phonegap-build

I have an issue where I am getting a "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova" error for iOS9.  This did not happen with Android and I can't figure out why it is happening on iOS9.  I am using (and a newbie to) PhoneGap Build and this is my 1st attempt to run my app on iOS.

I've looked through all suggested and related questions here I believe and did not find the answer.

So far I have attempted:

- running cordova in the console (same ReferenceError) adding
- cordova.js in the debugger (same error)

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have include cordova.js in your index.html file.

Comment: Yes, please check this.

Comment: Thank you Shanmugapriya!  I did have that in, in my console.  I am not sure why, however I am no longer getting this error.  Rather, now, "Device Not Ready" is not firing.  I have to look into this now.